# Fixing artifacts from an imported Medium sculpt?

Tags: edges, artifacts

I'm creating some assets for a game I'm making using Medium by Oculus, but when I import it into Blender it leaves me with strange lighting artifacts. I tried dissolving some vertices and edges to try and fix them but it would usually cause them to move a little bit.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxkll.jpg

This is an exported .obj of the sculpt with 10% of the polygons. If I do a 100% export (half a million polygons) the lighting artifacts aren't there until I decimate again in Blender. Also I'd like to figure out how to Make the edges harder and straighter, since that's how they were in the sculpt.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to model that from scratch cleanly?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic decimation on a hard edge model like this will always produce such artifacts.
Either you model with fewer polygons, so you do not have to decimate or you need to import the highres model into Blender and retopologize it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DD4jJc_01do